# Calling instance method of one ViewController from another ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I realize this question has been asked to death, at least once a month on stackoverflow for the last couple of years, but I still cannot find a solution.

I have two ViewControllers stemming from a UITabBarController.  Both are initialized through the storyboard.  I am attempting to call a method of one VC from another.  The instance method, of course.

[image]

I have heard of the following possibilities:

**1:** NSNotifications

**2:** Defining protocol and declaring one VC as the delegate of another.

**3:** Actually calling the method somehow through RootViewController.

I have the code working through NSNotifications, but I dislike the concept, and I would like to understand the correct way to do it.  I am most interested in possibility (3), then (2) as a last resort.

I tried to get (2) to work for several hours, but without initializing the delegate VC from the other VC, I am stumped. (Not an option due to storyboards).

**Is either (2) or (3) possible?  How so?**

What are my misunderstandings about preferred iOS architecture if neither are possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 3 is possible. Let's say you have two `UIViewController` classes, `FooViewController` (tab index 0) and `BarViewController` (tab index 1). And let's say you want to call `FooViewController`'s `-(void)doFoo` method from `BarViewController`.

In `BarViewController`, do `[(FooViewController *)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] doFoo]`.

Comment: ah ok, almost works. thanks a ton! I forgot to mention that FooViewController hides behind a UINavigationController. Sorry, I forgot to put that into my original post.  Could you please edit the code as per that scenario? http://image.bayimg.com/4877ae4d46dbdae21701f4648b51fcbe08e14c76.jpg (storyboard screen shot)

Comment: I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader =) Hint: `[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0].viewControllers` will give you the array of VCs in that `UINavigationController`.

Comment: hm... its complaining: Property 'viewControllers' not found on object of type 'id' when I try to NSLog the array...

Comment: So I re initialized the navigation controller... lets see what happens:

     
    UINavigationController *navController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [(homeViewController *) [navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] updateLabelsToMetric:metricSwitch.on];

Answer (score 0):

I guess using NSNOtification is not always a wrong way to do similar things. I also struggled for this concept.

for this senario, i think notification is okay:

1. you have a tabbarcontroller containing controller A and B
2. controller A is a listing of some objects, say, books.
3. controller B is controller for you to create a book by filling forms and click submit
4. controller A then update its listing.

the reason is that, the update of Controller A is not due to "clicking of submit". It refresh because a Book is created. It's about something for data. Somehow "A BOOK IS CREATED" is a critical event in an apps.

for another senario, it is not okay

1. you have a tabbarcontroller containing controller A and B
2. controller A has a ViewC at the center
3. controller B has a button, when it's clicked, the ViewC shift up

It's just my own opinion.